# Custom If tag in jsrender

Tags: jsrender

I try to create a custom if tag `contains` which check the given value within the array.

```
jQuery.views.tags({
       contains:{
            baseTag: "if", //no I18n
            init: function(){
                var valueArr = this.tagCtx.args[0];
                var findValue = this.tagCtx.args[1];

                return _.contains(valueArr, findValue);
            }
        },
});
```

But it doesn't work as I expected. Need an help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the init method. It is the render method you need to override.

See http://www.jsviews.com/#tags and http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/tags/extend-for or http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/range

```
jQuery.views.tags({
  contains:{
    baseTag: "if",
    render: function(valueArr, findValue) {
      if (valueArr && findValue) {
        // Call the base render method of the {{if}} tag,with the 'contains' result
        return this.base(_.contains(valueArr, findValue));
      }
      return this.base(); // {{else}} tag
    },
    // If using JsViews data-linking - need to override onUpdate too
    onUpdate: function(ev, eventArgs, tagCtxs) {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

Usage:

```
{{contains array1 item1}}
  ...
{{else array2 item2}}
  ...
{{/contains}}
```

(or `{^{contains ...}}` if using JsViews data-linking...)